# Polymorphic return type in c#

Tags: c#

I have a function that currently prototyped as:

```
List<object> get_object_list(byte object_type, object_void_delegate get_one_specific_type_object)
{}
```

As the logic of getting a list of elements is the same for all the types I have, but the logic for getting one element , is different from one type to another , I was hoping to have one function for getting all sort of list ( get_object_list() ).

for example for type `Car` I would call:

```
List<Car> cars_list = (List<Car>) get_object_list (CAR , get_one_car);
```

The problem now is I'm having c compilation error for invalid conversion:
cannot convert `List<object>` to `List<Car>`

Is there anyway to fix it?

***Update:***
Some clarifications.
get_object_list() is in a client component, and it gets it's data from network resource (a `NetStream`).
`object_type` is being sent to the server to let it know the desired list type.
Server will reply with a `Uint32 number_of_items` describing the number of elements available.
then, `get_one_specific_type_object()` will be called `number_of_items` times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to make the method generic:

```
List<T> GetObjectList<T>(byte objectType, Func<T> singleObjectGetter)
```

You'd call it as:

```
List<Car> cars = GetObjectList<Car>(CAR, GetOneCar);
```

Indeed you may well find that type inference allows you to just write:

```
List<Car> cars = GetObjectList(CAR, GetOneCar);
```

It's possible you want something like a `Func<int, T>` or similar - we can't really tell. It's also not clear what the first parameter is meant to be for, to be honest. If you need more detail than this, you should provide more context.

As a side note, I'd *strongly* encourage you to embrace C# / .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Generic method sounds like a good idea. please see my update for more details. I'm not fully familiar with generic methods though. can you please explain on `Func<T>  singleObjectGetter` ? is it a delegate?

Comment: @EdgarJamesluffternstat: Yes, `Func<T>` is a generic delegate which already exists in the `System` namespace.

Comment: will it take any delegate in actual call?

Comment: @EdgarJamesluffternstat: No, it will only take a `Func<T>` - but the call will *create* an appropriate delegate for any suitable method group you specify.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. btw, normally I write c/win32 , so I try to keep the camel case convention for the OS/environment names/functions.

Comment: @EdgarJamesluffternstat: You'd be better off using the conventions of the language you're writing in. Aside from anything else, that will help to *remind* you constantly which language you're using, so you use the idioms of that language as well as the naming conventions. It will also improve consistency between *your* method/type names and the methods/types you use from the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Although I imagine there should be better ways to implement your feature, this should do the trick to make your code work as it is.

```
List<Car> cars_list =  get_object_list (CAR , get_one_car)
        .Cast<Car>()
        .ToList()
```

Comment: Your `Select` would be better as `Cast<Car>` or `OfType<Car>` unless the OP *really* wants `null` entries for any value which isn't a `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of using [IEnumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb341406.aspx) method for this purpose.

A simple example may look like:

```
    var objectArray = new object[]{1,2,3,4,5,8};
    var intList = objectArray .Cast<int>()
```